# How to create image gallery gridview or Listview with rating images

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

I want to create a image gallery( gridview or listview ) with rating image.

Any tutorial or demo link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search at Google will find a lot take a look at these:

[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611106/New-ASP-NET-Image-Gallery-Control-coming-soon-in-v](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611106/New-ASP-NET-Image-Gallery-Control-coming-soon-in-vs)

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Image-Gallery-in-ASPNet-with-enlarge-image-preview-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

and

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-Rating-Control-Example.aspx

or 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418611/Simple-way-to-Design-Rating-in-ASP-NET-using-JavaS

Comment: Respectfully It is for **winform** but i want to create for **webform**

Comment: check it again I update it.